# Finding the following limit: $\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,1)}\frac{x^2-4y}{x-2y}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the following limit using trajectories:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,1)}\dfrac{x^2-4y}{x-2y}$$

But I am not sure how to define the trajectory when $x$ and $y$ have values more than $0$. For example, if I choose the equation: $y=mx$, how do I modify that equation so that it move in the same direction as $(x,y)\to(2,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trouble with $y = mx$ is that when $x\to 2$, then along the line $y = mx$, $y\to 2m$ which may or may not be equal to $1$. To remedy this, use $y =m(x-2)+1$ instead.

Thus,

$$\lim_{(x,m(x-2)+1)\to (2,1)} \frac{x^2-4y}{x-2y}=\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{x^2-4(m(x-2)+1)}{x-2(m(x-2)+1)}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}{=}\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{2x-4m}{1-2m} = \frac{4-4m}{1-2m}$$

which clearly depends on $m$, so the limit can't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = 2 +p$ and $y = 1 +q$ then

$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,1)}\dfrac{x^2-4y}{x-2y} = \lim_{(p,q)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{4p-4q}{p-2q} 
$$

So the limit actually only depends on the ratio $r= \dfrac{p}{q} $, since 
 $$
\lim_{(p,q)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{4p-4q}{p-2q} = \lim_{(p,q)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{4r-4}{r-2}
$$
However, since $\lim_{(p,q)\to(0,0)}r$ is not unique, the limit that you request does not exist.

Comment: What I don't understand is how you chose your trajectories?

Comment: Typographical remark: None of your `\large` is useful. Mathematical remark: None of the `\lim` exists hence they should not appear in your post.

Comment: The trajectories are (depending on the choice of r) $y-1  = q = p/r = (x-2)/r $ so $y = x/r + 1 + 2/r $. In other words, $m = 1/r$.

Comment: @Did thanks for editing away the useless \large

Comment: @Did Concerning the $\lim$, yes: one better writes $x = 2+p$ and $y = 1+p$ and discusses the case where both $p$ and $q$ are small but $\ne 0$. Then all transformations are fine. Only at the last step one then has to argue that $r = p/q$ is not unique as $p\to 0$ and simultaneously $q \to 0$.